# Compiling user-written source code files for beginners?

Tags: linux, fortran77

everyone.. I'm not a complete noob to linux, I'm using Fedora 16, but I've always had difficulty compiling programs from the command line and I would really like to learn how to do it the right way. I've had experience with Python, Ruby, Perl, PHP, Lua, bash and other languages, recently I've getting into Fortran code and here's the problem: Every time I run the f77 command with an option and filename, I get one of the following errors:
[code] 
[Eddie_Nygma@localhost ~]$ f77 -S #classicpayroll.f#
f77: no input files

[Eddie_Nygma@localhost ~]$ f77 -o #classicpayroll.f#
f77: argument to `-o' missing [/code]
I really need to get this compiled and running for my cs class, somebody please help me out, could it possibly be some sort of a a syntax error or how do I correct it?

Comment: Have you looked at the manual pages for your compiler? Does it behave like GCC in any way? If so, have a look at introductions to GCC. Typically the normal invocation is `gcc mysource.c` and nothing more. This will give you a binary named `a.out` unless you specify `-o mybinary`.

Comment: Probably more of a serverfault question: http://serverfault.com/ since it relates to linux commands rather than programming itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used fortran long ago.
In fortran, the first letter in file name shuold be A-Z or a-z.
number or # is not allowed

Comment: Actually, that goes for token names. A file is but a container, and it isn't significant to the compiler. It can be named however you wish. At least that has been the practice for some time now ...

Comment: Thanks, that got me a little furtheer along th process. Now I'm receiving these kinds of errors though,  what am I supposed to do next, change the code? I wrote it exactly as is written in the book.

Comment: This was my output after I took out the number signs, I'll show the entire code if no one can come up with a command-line solution: